# How to reference a script-local dictionary in a Vim mapping?

Tags: vim, scripting, function

Somehow I'm not able to execute the following mapping:

```
function! s:MySurroundingFunctionIWantToKeep()
  let s:Foobar={'foo': 'bar'}
  map \42 :echo <sid>Foobar.foo<cr>
endfunction
call s:MySurroundingFunctionIWantToKeep()
```

I thought it works the same way as it does with a script-local function:

```
function! s:MySurroundingFunctionIWantToKeep()
  function! s:Foobar()
    echo 'bar'
  endfunction
  map \42 :call <sid>Foobar()<cr>
endfunction
call s:MySurroundingFunctionIWantToKeep()
```

Also freeing `s:Foobar` from `s:MySurroundingFunctionIWantToKeep()` doesn't help, like:

```
let s:Foobar={'foo': 'bar'}
map \42 :echo <sid>Foobar.foo<cr>
```

Declaring the `s:Foobar` script-local variable as `g:Foobar` global variable does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way (that I know of) to directly access script-local variables outside the context of that script; `<SID>` only works for functions (and only in mappings).

You could provide indirect access through a function, though:

```
function! s:FoobarHash()
  return s:Foobar
endfunction
function! s:MySurroundingFunctionIWantToKeep()
  let s:Foobar={'foo': 'bar'}
  map \42 :echo <sid>FoobarHash()['foo']<cr>
endfunction
call s:MySurroundingFunctionIWantToKeep()
```

Depending on how isolated you want to keep the variable, you could make the “accessor” function more restrictive (only allow certain keys, only allow read access, only allow writes to certain keys, etc).

```
let s:Foobar={'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'quux'}
function! s:FoobarAccess(...)
  " Provide limited access to the script-local hash s:Foobar

  if a:0 == 1
    " allow read access to all keys
    return s:Foobar[a:1]

  elseif a:0 == 2
    " allow write access to only 'foo'
    if a:1 !=# 'foo'
      throw 'FoobarAccess: not allowed to write to key ' . a:1
    endif
    let old = s:Foobar[a:1]
    let s:Foobar[a:1] = a:2
    return old

  else
    throw 'FoobarAccess must take exactly one or two arguments'
  endif
endfunction


map \42 :echo <sid>FoobarAccess('foo')<cr>
map \43 :echo <sid>FoobarAccess('foo','new value')<cr>
map \44 :echo <sid>FoobarAccess('baz')<cr>
map \45 :echo <sid>FoobarAccess('baz',1)<cr>
```

Comment: It's a pity. I actually try to make a dictionary's functions eligible for mappings, i.e. expose the object's behaviour much like I would do with a script-local function object. Also I can't see a problem why Vim would prevent such an access pattern.